# Special Realtivity: Kinematic experiment in a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises

If I perform a kinematic experiment in a car driving exactly 55 mph on a flat road, and perform the same experiment in a lab would their be any difference in results between the two experiments?  Basically would I be able to tell which one I did in the car?

Answer (score 2):

The first postulate in special relativity states that laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames. Therefore, there will be no difference between the two experiments provided you observe each one in its frame.

However, if you observed the two experiments from the same frame, one of them will undergo time dilation and be slower than the other.

Comment: Thanks!   Having a bit of trouble with the "frames".   Is there a good resource you could recommend?

Comment: @Jb521 the Feynman lectures on physics are about as good as it gets.  http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_15.html

Comment: @AOrtiz I don't think the Feynman lectures are a good place to start for anyone just starting out, especially so for the section on special relativity.  For one, it starts with the outmoded concept of relativistic mass.  Another is it presents a lot of results without a clear explanation of how and why.  No mention of the invariant interval.   Better for a novice is "Spacetime Physics" by Taylor and Wheeler (preferably the first edition).   I had no trouble getting through it when I was in high school, and the lessons have stayed with me.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference assuming you throw the objects with the same initial velocity, at the same angle of attack and maintain the same distance from the experiment. That's mainly because while inside the car, the thrown object has an initial velocity of n+velocity of the car, thus not moving when the car is the point of reference.

Comment: Please try to give reasons for your answer. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more about answering questions.